# Fetching distinct rows from multiple joins SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have one main table called deliveries and it has one to many relationship with deliveries_languages as dl, deliveries_markets dm and deliveries_tags dt having delivery_id as foreign key. These 3 tables have one to one relation with languages , markets and tags respectively.  Additionaly, deliveries, table have one to one relation with companies and have company_is as foreign key. Following is a query that I have written:

```
SELECT deliveries.*, languages.display_name, markets.default_name, tags.default_name, companies.name
FROM deliveries
JOIN deliveries_languages dl ON dl.delivery_id = deliveries.id 
JOIN deliveries_markets dm ON dm.delivery_id = deliveries.id 
JOIN deliveries_tags dt ON dt.delivery_id = deliveries.id 
JOIN languages ON languages.id = dl.language_id 
JOIN markets ON markets.id = dm.market_id 
JOIN tags ON tags.id = dt.tag_id 
JOIN companies ON companies.id = deliveries.company_id 
WHERE 
deliveries.name ILIKE '%new%' AND 
deliveries.created_by = '5f331347-fb58-4f63-bcf0-702f132f97c5' AND 
deliveries.deleted_at IS NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

Here I am getting redundant delivery_ids because for each delivery_id there are multiple languages, markets and tags. I want to use limit on distinct delivery_ids. So, limit 10 should not give me 10 records from above join query but 10 records where there is distinct delivery_id (deliveries.id). I probably can use derived table concept here but I am not sure how can I do that. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: How to chose these 10 rows per delivery_id? (Keeping several languages seems a bit odd.)

Comment: I am using postgreSQL

Comment: Basically I want to do group by on deliveries.id. It is possible using subquery but I dont know how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.id) d.*, l.display_name, m.default_name, t.default_name, c.name
FROM deliveries d JOIN
     deliveries_languages dl
     ON dl.delivery_id = d.id JOIN
     deliveries_markets dm
     ON dm.delivery_id = d.id JOIN
     deliveries_tags dt
     ON dt.delivery_id = d.id JOIN
     languages l
     ON l.id = dl.language_id JOIN
     markets m
     ON m.id = dm.market_id JOIN
     tags
     ON t.id = dt.tag_id JOIN
     companies c
     ON  c.id = d.company_id 
WHERE d.name ILIKE '%new%' AND 
      d.created_by = '5f331347-fb58-4f63-bcf0-702f132f97c5' AND 
      d.deleted_at IS NULL 
ORDER BY d.id
LIMIT 10;
```

For larger amounts of data, this can be very inefficient.  Multiple junction tables result in Cartesian products when used like this.  However, for a smallish amount of data, this should solve your problem.

Comment: This is working for me. But you said performance would hamper. Is it because of multiple joins or because of DISTINCT ON clause? Also, is it more efficient than using subquery?

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade . . . It is because the joins are producing a Cartesian product across different dimensions . . . for a given delivery, the intermediate results is the number of languages times the number of markets times the number of tags.